# How to convert an object having rows into a datatable

Tags: c#

I have an object that has 14 objects inside it . Each object contains my row values. How do I put everyting into a datatable using C#

Comment: come on.... at least TRY something

Comment: could you provide some code? how can we know how is your objects and properties look like without seeing any code?

Comment: try using your object as a datasource for your datatable.  see if that works.  if not, post a question with specific code and errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
static DataTable GetTable(List<Object> yourObjectList)
{
// This is assuming you have a list of objects
var _firstObject = yourObjectList.First();
var table = new DataTable();

// Do this multiple times for each parameter you have. 
table.Columns.Add(_firstObject.ParamaterName, typeof(string));

foreach(var obj in yourObjectList)
{
table.Rows.Add(obj.ParamaterName, obj.ParamaterName2, etc);
}
return table;
}
```

I'm assuming you have a list of objects with multiple properties. You need to add a column for each property to the table, then iterate over the list and add rows for each object.

Answer (score 0):

```
datatable table= new datatable ();
foreach(var item in yourObjec)
{
table.Rows.Add(item.objectvalue);
}
```